# Chrome users can not select text from asp.net website pages

Tags: asp.net, css, google-chrome, stylesheet, textselection

I have been debugging this but not getting anywhere.

Some of the pages in the website doesn't allow users to select an area of the page and copy. Nothing happens when they try to select and the text doesn't get highlighted as well as they can't copy.

I tried to look for "user-select:none" in the stylesheet as well as view-source but there is none.

I am trying to debug using chrome developer tools but not getting anywhere. I am thinking the z-index could be problem but not sure where to fix it?

Can anyone suggest?

Comment: Added the site link. I see some down votes. Please explain why so that I wont repeat if there is any mistake or issue.

Comment: You have the entire page inside a <`form>`. It should not be laid out like this.

Comment: @Vector: Can you give some suggestions for me to fix the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the link you give on the `style_accordion.css` you have this style:

```
body{
  position:relative;
  margin:0;

  font-family:arial;
  -webkit-touch-callout:none;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;  /*<-- this line for chrome */
}
```

that prevent the selection on entire page.

Comment: -> I would like to know what steps you did to debug this? This will help me next time if something similar happens.

Comment: -> Sorry Aristos. My mistake. I forgot.

Comment: @Anirudh I did nothing more than a search... (really).

Comment: Can you remove the public facing URL from your answer? That link may not be valid as I am removing it from public facing. Thanks.. I have marked this as answered.

Comment: @Anirudh - yes no problem (you can also do that you know). (I do it)